# Rebuild nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an nested array that i want to rebuild based on age value:

```
//Data
data = {"people": 
   [{"male_1": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"31"}
    ]}, 
   {"female_2": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "23"}
   ]}
   [{"male_3": [
     {"name": "Tom" ,"age": "31"}, 
     {"name":"John", "age":"29"}
    ]}, ...
  ]}
```

New array should looks like:

```
people = [{"male_1": [
       {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}
     ]},
     [{"male_3": [
       {"name": "Tom" ,"age": "31"}
    ]}, 
    {"female_2": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"} 
   ]}, ...
  ]}
```

Based on this example i need to find the largest age of all "persons" then add this person to array then do same with the next one. The age can be same in this case there is no difference who goes first.

With the next function i can find first one and push it to new array, but how find next one?

```
var age = 0;

data["people"].forEach(function(item) { 
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            item[key].forEach(function(person) {
                if (person.age > age) {
                    age = person.age;
                    oldest_person = person

                }

            });
        }
    }
});
console.log(oldest_person);
```

Comment: Did you consider using Angulars [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)?

Comment: You meant custom filter? I need to rebuild it inside controller not inside an `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 1):

here is another interpretation. This one uses the native `Array.prototype.sort` as the helper function.

```js
var data = { "people": [{ "male_1": [{ "name": "Bob", "age": "32" }, { "name": "Mike", "age": "31" }] }, { "female_2": [{ "name": "Jessica", "age": "24" }, { "name": "Ann", "age": "23" }] }, { "male_3": [{ "name": "Tom", "age": "31" }, { "name": "John", "age": "29" }] }] },
 oldies = [],
 peopleByAge = data.people.map(function(group){

 for( var name in group ){
  group[name] = group[name].sort(sortBy('age'));
  oldies.push( group[name][0] );
 }

 return group;
});
// sort by an object key
function sortBy( key ){
 return function(a, b){
  return parseInt(a[ key ]) < parseInt(b[ key ]);
 }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify({ oldies: oldies.sort(sortBy('age')), peopleByAge: peopleByAge }, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var age = 0;
var oldest_person = [];
var data = {"people": 
   [
   {"male_1": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"31"}
   ]},
   {"female_2": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "23"}
   ]},
   {"male_3": [
     {"name": "Tom" ,"age": "31"}, 
     {"name":"John", "age":"29"}
   ]}
]};

data["people"].forEach(function(item) { 
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var age = 0;
            var name = key;
            var oldest = null;
            item[key].forEach(function(person) {
                // Determine the oldest person in each group ("male_1", "female_2", "male_3", ...)
                if (person.age > age) {
                    age = person.age;
                    oldest = person;
                }
            });
            // Push the oldest person into the 'oldest_person' array
            var group = {};
            group[name] = [ oldest ];
            oldest_person.push(group);
        }
    }
});

console.log(oldest_person);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `Array` methods, like [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
var data = { "people": [{ "male_1": [{ "name": "Bob", "age": "32" }, { "name": "Mike", "age": "31" }] }, { "female_2": [{ "name": "Jessica", "age": "24" }, { "name": "Ann", "age": "23" }] }, { "male_3": [{ "name": "Tom", "age": "31" }, { "name": "John", "age": "29" }] }] },
    people = [];
data.people.forEach(function (a) {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
        var o = {};
        o[k] = a[k].reduce(function (c, d) {
            return c.age > d.age ? c : d;
        });
        people.push(o);
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(people, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```